# Eclipse failed to include google play services

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying out android gcm in eclipse. I have successfully completed the http server implementation but then i get an error in the manifest file around @integer/ play.

I have tried importing the jar manually but it doesn't work.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the [instructions](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) carefully.

1. Make sure that both the project library and the application project that depends on it are in your workspace. If one of the projects is missing, import it into your workspace.
2. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
3. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
4. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
5. From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
6. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
7. Click OK to close the Properties window.

Basically, you have to import the Google Play Services project, then add it as a library in the project.